# git checkout getting ASCII file instead of binary

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-lfs

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a fresh PC and a binary file gets cloned out as a text file.

Ran command on both old and new boxes:

```
$ git checkout -f a8afd894150cc31cde43dbeb422183640b64dcab
HEAD is now at a8afd8941 did some stuff.
```

old PC:

```
file composer.phar
composer.phar: data
```

new PC:

```
$ file composer.phar
composer.phar: ASCII text
```

After seeing it fails, I installed/enabled git lfs:

```
$ apt-get install git-lfs 
$ git lfs install
Updated git hooks.
Git LFS initialized.
```

Both `/root/.gitconfig` and `/var/lib/jenkins/.gitconfig` look identical on old and new PCs.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The files that you have on disk are called LFS pointer files, and they're the way that Git LFS keeps track of data.  If when you did the checkout, Git LFS wasn't installed or you hadn't run `git lfs install` already, then Git wouldn't have invoked Git LFS to check out the real large files, and it would have left the pointer files in the tree.

The easiest way to recover from this is to run `git lfs pull`, which will download and check out all the files in your working tree.  Since you've run `git lfs install`, Git should invoke Git LFS the next time you switch branches, and everything should happen automatically.

For reference, the entries you're looking for in the `.gitconfig` files are these:

```
$ git config -l | grep filter.lfs
filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
```

They're automatically set up by `git lfs install`, but you can set them manually if that's more convenient.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. Ran `git lfs pull` and it indeed did checkout the files correctly (even though after running `git lfs install` I'd tried deleting the directory and running `git checkout -f a8afd894150cc31cde43dbeb422183640b64dcab` again, only to pull text files again). Looks like jenkins, on the other hand, still pulls text files, but that's another issue.

Comment: Same problem here.