# Git: Binary files turning into ASCII text files upon check out

Tags: linux, git, unity-game-engine, binary, ascii

I'm currently working on a Unity game with a friend who is using Windows and I'm on Linux. After cloning the Git Repo none of the images (*.jpg, *.png) are able to be loaded. Using the 'file' command reveals that the file types are 'ASCII text' and they can't be opened with a simple image program. That would be my suspicion as to why Unity doesn't know what to do with them either and they can't be imported.

I thought it would have something to do with the .gitattributes file and we are currently using the one found here - https://gist.github.com/nemotoo/b8a1c3a0f1225bb9231979f389fd4f3f

Can someone explain to me what is happening here and what I can do about it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git checkout getting ASCII file instead of binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172926/git-checkout-getting-ascii-file-instead-of-binary)

Comment: Maybe remove the `-text` in the `.gitattributes`?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies... this question is a duplicate. Solution found here - [git checkout getting ASCII file instead of binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172926/git-checkout-getting-ascii-file-instead-of-binary)